# How using search filter variable from header search field in different component angular

Tags: angular, typescript, search, filter, components

I am using the angular search filter. It works fine using it in the same component. But I want to have my search field in the header and the results are in another component.
Here is my difficulty.
I read that I can get the searchText variable with the @Input Decorator
But somehow it doesn't work for me or maybe I am using it totally wrong.
here is a snippet of my header.component.html

```
<form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>
              <input type="text" name="searchText" placeholder="Search movie title..."
                     [(ngModel)]="searchText">
            </label>
          </div>
          <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
        </form>
```

here the header.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
  }

  @Output() public sideNavToggle = new EventEmitter();

  searchText!: string;
  @Output() searchTextEvent: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onToggleSidenav = () => {
    this.sideNavToggle.emit();
  }
  setSearchText(){
    this.searchTextEvent.emit(this.searchText);
  }
}
```

and here the movie-list.component.html this is the component to show the results

```
...
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let movie of movies | filter: searchText" hideToggle>
...
```

movie-list.component.ts

```
import {Component, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Movie} from '../movie.model';
import {MovieService} from '../movie.service';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';
import {HeaderComponent} from '../../header/header.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie-list',
  templateUrl: './movie-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie-list.component.css'],
  providers: [HeaderComponent]
})

export class MovieListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @Input() searchText!: string;
  movies: Movie[] = [];
  isLoading = false;
  private moviesSub!: Subscription; 

  constructor(public movieService: MovieService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.movieService.getMovies();
    this.moviesSub = this.movieService.getMovieUpdateListener().subscribe((movies: Movie[]) => {
      this.isLoading = false;
      this.movies = movies;
    });
  }
}
```

and finally my app.component.html

```
<app-header (sideNavToggle)="sidenav.toggle()"></app-header>
...
<main>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can approch solutions for this problem in multiple ways.

one simpler way is as following.
Store the search text as the service variable and bind that variable to input. and use same variable for filter this will allow you to share variable without any complex code.

if you want to be efficient solution then create a behaviour subject and use async pipe.

and in your code i think there are some bits missing as well like there is no info how the searchText is in  movie-list component.

Comment: Do you have a link for me to read about how to use this way?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it working by using a Subject and observe the searchText.